# How to transfer files to a mobile device over a wireless network using (C#)

Tags: c#, compact-framework

we are planning to a C# Compact Framework application using Mobile Client Software Factory. The application should talk to a content server(we are building the content server) using WiFi network and download the required files to the mobile device. Download size may be appox 30 MB to 60 MB.

Do we need to use FTP to download the files? or is there any other mechanism in which we can download them.

I'm new to Mobile Application development.

Answer (score 1):

You have the option of using shared folders on Windows Mobile devices and just doing a file copy.

Or you can go the FTP/Web download approach.

I think both work equally well.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446527.aspx), which is on MSDN with the title of Developing Smart Device WiFi Applications with the .NET Compact Framework. This should definately get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your transfer needs, and if you have a desktop component to your app, a simple, proprietary socket protocol would be really easy to roll for file transfers.